# Egyptian fractions with very large denominators

Tags: reference-request, algorithms, egyptian-fractions

It is well-known that if we have a fraction $\frac ab$, with $a,b\in\mathbb N$ and $a<b$, if we apply the [greedy algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm_for_Egyptian_fractions) in order to express it as a sum of unit fractions, then we may get fractions with very large denominators. For instance, if we apply the algorithm to $\frac5{31}$, what we get is$$\frac17+\frac1{55}+\frac1{3\,979}+\frac1{23\,744\,683}+\frac1{1\,127\,619\,917\,796\,295}$$and if we apply it to $\frac{1\,197}{2\,273}$, then the decimal representation of the last denominator has $14\,583$ digits. All this suggests that the following statement is true:

> If $R>0$, then there are natural numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $a<b$ and that, if we apply the greedy algorithm to express $\frac ab$ as the sum of unit fractions, then one of the unit fractions $\frac1D$ that we get in that expression will be such that $\frac Db>R$.

My guess is that either this statement has already been proved or that it has already been stated as a conjecture. It that's so, can someone please provide a reference?

Comment: promising: http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ronspubs/13_03_Egyptian.pdf

Comment: https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/numth/egypt/approx.html

Comment: It may be worth trying to find Mays, Michael, A worst case of the Fibonacci-Sylvester expansion, The Journal of Combinatorial Mathematics and Combinatorial Computing 1 (1987) 141-148.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a very simple answer to the original question. The greedy algorithm, applied to $a/b=2/(2n-1)$, gives $${2\over2n-1}={1\over n}+{1\over n(2n-1)}$$ so in the notation of the original question we have $${D\over b}={n(2n-1)\over2n-1}=n$$ which can be made arbitrarily large.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question which already has an answer, but it is still interesting to try to maximize $D$, in terms of $a$ and $b$. By the greedy algorithm, we get $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{1}{\left \lceil \frac{b}{a} \right \rceil} + \frac{a \left \lceil \frac{b}{a} \right \rceil - b}{b \left \lceil \frac{b}{a} \right \rceil}$.

Since $a \left \lceil \frac{b}{a} \right \rceil - b$ (which is the numerator of the latter fraction) is strictly smaller than $a$, we know the greedy algorithm terminates in at most $a-1$ steps. If it takes exactly $a-1$ steps, then by induction we see $D = D_{a-1}$, where $D_0 = b$ and $D_i = D_{i-1} \left \lceil \frac{D_{i-1}}{a-i+1} \right \rceil$ for $1 \le i \le a-1$.

By Corollary 2 of [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268859222_A_worst_case_of_the_Fibonacci-Sylvester_expansion) paper (which was referenced by Gerry Myerson in the comments), for every $a \in \mathbb{N}$ there are infinitely many $b > a$ such that the greedy algorithm applied to the fraction $\frac{a}{b}$ does indeed take $a-1$ steps to terminate. Assume $\frac{a}{b}$ is such a fraction with $a > 1$. Since $D_i = D_{i-1} \left \lceil \frac{D_{i-1}}{a-i+1} \right \rceil > \frac{D_{i-1}^2}{a}$, by induction this gives us $D = D_{a-1} > b\left(\frac{b}{a} \right)^{2^{a-1}-1}$. This means that if we fix $a$, then there is a constant $c = c(a) > 0$ such that there are infinitely many $b$ with $D > cb^{2^{a-1}}$. This is essentially best possible, since we always have $D_i \le D_{i-1}^2$ implying, once again by induction, $D \le b^{2^{a-1}}$ for all fractions $\frac{a}{b}$. To summarize:

**Theorem**.
For a fraction $\frac{a}{b}$ with $1 \le a < b$, let $D = D(a,b)$ be the largest denominator that occurs in the greedy egyptian expanion of $\frac{a}{b}$. Then $D \le b^{2^{a-1}}$. On the other hand, for every $a \in \mathbb{N}$ there is a positive constant $c = c(a)$ such that for infinitely many positive integers $b \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $D > cb^{2^{a-1}}$.

Comment: Are you arguing that for *every* fraction $\frac ab$ which takes $a-1$ steps to terminate,  we will get $D > c b^{2^{a-1}}$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. In fact, when you need $k$ steps, you will get $D > cb^{2^k}$, since you are basically squaring the denominator in every step.

Answer (score 3):

First, can you establish that the algorithm always halts for this problem?

The reason I ask, is that several years ago, it was (and I believe still is) an **open problem** that if $\frac{a}{b}$ is a rational number with $b$ odd---

> Can $\frac{a}{b}$ be expressed as $\sum \frac{1}{x_{i}}$, where the $x_{i}$ are chosen to be the least possible odd integers that leave a nonnegative remainder, in a finite number of terms?

This problem received a fair amount of attention from Richard K. Guy in his *Unsolved Problems in Number Theory,* 3rd Edition. In it, he highlights some of the efforts by certain individuals, such as Stan Wagon, who has tackled the fraction $\frac{3}{179}$, which produced 19 terms, the last of which has 439492 digits. This, Guy indicates was beaten by David Baily who considered $\frac{3}{2879}$ and used the greedy algorithm to expand it to the sum of 21 unit fractions, the last term of which has 3018195 digits. Later, it was shown that $\frac{5}{5809}$ has at least 22 terms with the last being in excess of 60,000,000 digits.

Incidentally, although the 3rd edition of Guy's book is the most recent, it was however, published in 2005. Nevertheless, it seems that the problem is still open. See, for instance:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/100265/not-especially-famous-long-open-problems-which-anyone-can-understand/203587#203587

I hope this puts a little bit of light on the problem.

Comment: Yes, it always halts, in no more than $a-1$ steps. This is a standard induction problem.

Comment: That may very well be, for odd $b$, a new result, because in Guy's book he definitely speaks of that as an open problem. Of course, it may have been proven since Guy published the 3rd edition, but I doubt it. I hope to look into that in the next day or two.

Comment: The problem mentioned by Guy adds the extra hypothesis that the $x_i$'s are odd.

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Comment: It appears that this problem is still open. Please see: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/100265/not-especially-famous-long-open-problems-which-anyone-can-understand/203587#203587

Comment: Let's be clear here. The problem with odd denominators is (as far as I know) still open. Without that restriction, the problem of whether the greedy algorithm always terminates is an easy exercise, with an affirmative answer.

Comment: Yes. Where the denominators are odd. That problem appears to be still open.