# Egyptian fractions: does the greedy algorithm never give more fractions than absolutely necessary?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fractions, egyptian-fractions

Given $n > 1$, it's obvious that $$\frac{2^n - 1}{2^n} = \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{2^i}.$$

For example, $$\frac{15}{16} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{16}.$$ That's not the answer we'd get using the greedy algorithm, since after taking one half, it would take one third instead of one quarter: $$\frac{15}{16} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{240}.$$

That last denominator is a little larger than I'd like, but it's still just four fractions.

My main question is: does the greedy algorithm ever give more fractions than some other algorithm?

Maybe if we require the fractions to be distinct, e.g., in [Egyptian fractions with very large denominators](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2857463/egyptian-fractions-with-very-large-denominators), Mr. Santos gives $$\frac{5}{31} = \frac1 7 + \frac 1 {55} + \frac 1 {3\,979} + \frac 1 {23\,744\,683} + \frac 1 {1\,127\,619\,917\,796\,295},$$ which is preferable to $$\frac{5}{31} = 5 \times \frac{1}{31}$$ only because of the distinct fraction requirement.

Then if the... sorry, my ride to vote is here, and then dinner

Comment: At least for $\frac{2^n - 1}{2^n}$, the greedy algorithm might give fewer fractions than adding up $2^n$ for $n = -1, -2, -3, \ldots$, but depending on the implementation, might take a very long time to give the answer.

Answer (score 3):

My interpretation of your hypothesis is: The Greedy Algorithm never gives more Egyptian Fractions than the minimum number "easily proven" necessary.

If you start with the fraction $\frac{n}{m}$ where $(m>n)$ then it can always be split into a sum of $n$ positive Egyptian fractions, but depending on the particular denominator $m$ chosen, less Egyptian Fractions may be needed as an easily provable minimum.

Taking your example with $n=5$ we can split the denominators into even $(2q)$ and odd $(2q+1)$

Case Even Denominator:
$$\frac{5}{2q}=\frac{1}{2q}+ \frac{2}{q}$$
If $q$ is even, $2$ Egyptian fractions are required. If $q$ is odd, then $\frac{2}{q}$ can always be written as the sum of two different Egyptian fractions e.g. $$\frac{2}{2t+1}=\frac{1}{t+1}+\frac{1}{(t+1)(2t+1)},$$ giving a minimum of $3$ Egyptian fractions.
Therefore in the case of an even denominator the greedy algorithm should not exceed $2$ Egyptian fractions if $q$ is even and $3$ Egyptian Fractions if $q$ is odd for your hypothesis to hold true for $n=5$.

Case Odd Denominator:
$$\frac{5}{2q+1}=\frac{1}{2q+1}+ \frac{2}{q+1} +\frac{2}{(q+1)(2q+1)}$$
In the case of $q$ odd the spilt into 3 Egyptian fractions is obvious, in the case q is even and $(q=2u)$ five Egyptian fractions are needed as a simply provable minimum
$$\frac{5}{4u+1}=\frac{1}{4u+1}+ \frac{1}{u+1} +\frac{1}{(u+1)(2u+1)}+ \frac{1}{(u+1)(4u+1)} +\frac{1}{(u+1)(2u+1)(4u+1)}$$

Therefore in the case of an odd denominator with $q$ odd the greedy algorithm should give no more than $3$ Egyptian fractions and with $q$ even no more than $5$ Egyptian fractions for your hypothesis to hold true for $n=5$.

In the last case if the [Erdős-Straus conjecture](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450280/erd%C5%91s-straus-conjecture) is proved true then the maximum number of Egyptian fractions needed can be reduced to 4 I think for $n=5$, but I don't think you need this level of analysis to prove your hypothesis wrong in general.

For any value $n$ you can find values of $m$ which will give a split into $2$ Egyptian fractions and $3$ and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The question is "does the greedy algorithm never give more fractions than absolutely necessary?". That is, more than the smallest number $k$ of fractions in *any* representation. Which might be larger than the smallest number "easily proven" necessary, if it is considered that the need for $k$ terms cannot be proven easily.

The OP gives the greedy algorithm's 5-term representation for $5/31$. Sierpinski conjectured that $5/n$ for $n\geqslant3$ has a 3-term representation, and $5/31$ is not a counterexample: $$\frac5{31}=\frac18+\frac1{31}+\frac1{248}.$$

There are rationals $4/n$ where the greedy algorithm gives a 4-term representation. The one of least $n$ is $4/17$, for which this greedy representation, and a 3-term one, are as follows:
$$\frac4{17}=\frac1{5}+\frac1{29}+\frac1{1233}+\frac1{3039345}=\frac1{6}+\frac1{17}+\frac1{102}.$$

Answer (score 1):

No: It's easy to find examples of distinct $m$ and $n$ such that the greedy algorithm applied to $\frac1m+\frac1n$ yields more than two terms. One simple such example is
$$
\frac14+\frac15=\frac13+\frac19+\frac1{180}.
$$